# Spock to provide temporary files for the Gradle task method within expect: and where: blocks

Tags: gradle, spock

I would like to use Spock's Data Driven Testing.

My task has a method with a `File` argument to process. Result is an `Array` with processed lines. If there is nothing valid to process mentioned array will have 0 size. I used a JUnit rule for creating a temporary folder and I suspect it's the problem.

How can I solve this ?

```
class H2JSpec extends Specification {

   @Rule
   TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder
   @Shared
   private ArrayList<File> tempFiles = []

   def "let's build the mappings for template"() {
      setup:
      Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
      H2JTask task = project.task('h2j', type: H2JTask)

      def inputs = ["""#dsfs

""",
    """#this file defines the mapping of h files declarations into java errorcodes: autoenum=off prefix=ec_ class=test.framework.base.MsgErrorCodes
"""]

      tempFiles.add(temporaryFolder.newFile('1.txt'))
      tempFiles.add(temporaryFolder.newFile('2.txt'))

      tempFiles[0].withWriter { it << inputs[0] }
      tempFiles[1].withWriter { it << inputs[1] }

      expect:
      task.prepareCommandList(a).size() == b

      where:
      a || b
      tempFiles[0] || 0
      tempFiles[1] || 1

   }
}
```

And the result is the `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I'd eliminate use of `Rule` at all and rewrite the test in the following way:

```
@Grab(group='org.spockframework', module='spock-core', version='1.0-groovy-2.4')

import spock.lang.*

class H2JSpec extends Specification {

  def "let's build the mappings for template"() {
    setup:
      def task = new A()

    when:
      def f = File.createTempFile('aaa', 'bbb')
      f.write(a)

    then:
      task.prepareCommandList(f).size() == b

    where:

      a          || b
      """#dsfs

    """          || 3
      """#this file defines the mapping of h files declarations into java errorcodes: autoenum=off prefix=ec_ class=test.framework.base.MsgErrorCodes
    """          || 2

  }
}

class A {
   List<String> prepareCommandList(File f) {
    f.readLines()
  }
}
```

Comment: That is very smooth, indeed when it comes to the processing sets of the test data we just need a one file to work with.

How would you deal with the input data in multilne strings ? I've hidden them behind extra variable. Can we somehow externalize them more - to treat them as the resources for the tests ?

        where:
        a << inputs
        b << [0,1]

Comment: @Piotr, probably I'd put the multiline strings in the files that are kept under `src/test/resources`. This way you already have a file - just need to load it. Also the test becomes more clear since you don't need all these temporary folders, files, whatever that only obscure the test. If you move use files you can both use a spock data table or a list - as in comment. Both are good.

Comment: Good solution. I'd recommend that you do `f.deleteOnExit()` after assigning `f` to the temporary file, to ensure that the temporary file is deleted on test termination.